# RabbitMQ as Spring Cloud Bus in Kubernetes for Spring Boot Applications

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I have developed Spring Boot applications. I have setup admin and RabbitMQ as well as spring cloud bus. When i refresh the end points of applications, it refreshes the properties for application.

Can anyone please help me how to setup RabbitMQ in kubernetes now? I did research to an extent and found in few articles that it needs to be deployed as "Statefulset" rather than "Deployment" https://notallaboutcode.blogspot.de/2017/09/rabbitmq-on-kubernetes-container.html. I could not get why this needs to be done exactly. Also any useful link on deploying RabbitMQ in kubernetes would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're looking to do and what tools you have available. I guess your current setup is much like that described in  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bus. One approach to porting that to kubernetes might be to try to get your setup working with docker-compose first and then you could port that docker-compose to kubernetes deployment descriptors.

A simple way to deploy rabbitmq in k8s would be to set up a Deployment using a rabbitmq docker image. An example of this is https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-examples/blob/fe732096b5a19de0ad44879a399053f6ae02b095/kubernetes/kubectl/infrastructure.yml#L17. (Notice that file isn't radically different from a docker-compose file so you could port from one to the other.) But that won't be persisting data outside of the Pods so if the cluster were to go down or the Pod/s were to go down then you'd lose message data. The persistence is ephemeral.

So to have non-ephemeral persistence you could instead use a StatefulSet as in the example you point to. Another example is https://wesmorgan.svbtle.com/rabbitmq-cluster-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets

If you are using helm (or can use helm) then you could use the [rabbitmq helm chart](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/stable/rabbitmq), [which uses a StatefulSet](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/rabbitmq/templates/statefulset.yaml#L2).

But if your only reason for needing the bus is to trigger refreshes when property changes happen then there are alternative paths available with Kubernetes. I'm guessing you need the hot reloads so you could look at using https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes#propertysource-reload Or if you need the config to come from git specifically then you could look at http://fabric8.io/guide/develop/configuration.html (If you didn't need the hot reloads or git then you could consider versioning your configmaps and upgrading them with your application upgrades like in https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-java-apps-with-kubernetes-configmaps-a )

Comment: This will help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I thought spring cloud kubernetes suites best for the case we have. So i tried using `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config` as a dependency in pom.xml. and then i created config map for the application as mentioned with the same name as provided in the application. properties file. But it is not loading the properties from it. is there anything else that i need to configure?

Comment: Fabric8 provide the full source code of an example at https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/tree/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-examples/kubernetes-reload-example Presumably something in your setup doesn't match theirs. I'd start by double-checking the spring.application.name matches the configmap name then look at whether you're using ConfigurationProperties like they do and then compare the pom dependencies. There's another example at https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/10/23/hot-reconfiguration-of-microservices-on-kubernetes/

Comment: Spring Cloud Kubernetes is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed helm in your cluster

```
helm install stable/rabbitmq
```

This will install rabbitmqserver on your cluster, the following commands are for obtaining the password and erlang cookie, replace **prodding-wombat-rabbitmq** for w/e kubernetes decides to name the pod.

```
kubectl get secret --namespace default prodding-wombat-rabbitmq -o jsonpath="{.data.rabbitmq-password}" | base64 --decode

kubectl get secret --namespace default prodding-wombat-rabbitmq -o jsonpath="{.data.rabbitmq-erlang-cookie}" | base64 --decode
```

To connect to the pod:

```
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=prodding-wombat-rabbitmq" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
```

Then prorxy to localhost so you can connect in your browswer

```
kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 5672:5672 15672:15672
```